# struct with mapping member in solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, mapping, struct

I have the below struct in a contract:

```
struct ServiceListStruct {
string cloudID;
address gatewayID;
string serviceProducerID;
mapping (string => string) serviceProducerMetadata;
string serviceConsumerMetaAttr;
string accessControlModel;
}
ServiceListStruct[] public BCServiceList;

ServiceListStruct sls;
```

Also a function to add struct elements to the array as below:

```
function addEntry(string _cloudID, address _gatewayID, string _serviceProducerID, string _serviceProducerMetadata, string _serviceConsumerMetaAttr, string _accessControlModel) public returns (uint)
{
require(msg.sender==_gatewayID);
sls.cloudID = _cloudID;
sls.gatewayID = _gatewayID;
sls.serviceProducerID = _serviceProducerID;
sls.serviceConsumerMetaAttr = _serviceConsumerMetaAttr;
sls.accessControlModel = _accessControlModel;
//
string memory s1;
string memory s2 = _serviceProducerMetadata;
string  memory s3;
bytes memory s2bytes = bytes(_serviceProducerMetadata);
while(s2bytes.length != 0)
{
   (s1,s2) = splitString(s2,";");
   (s1,s3) = splitString(s1,":");
   sls.serviceProducerMetadata[s1] =s3;
   s2bytes = bytes(s2);
}
BCServiceList.push(sls);
return 1;
}
```

The logic of split string function is as below:

```
function splitString(string _s, string _seperator) public returns(string, string)
{
var s_slice = _s.toSlice();
var seperator_slice = _seperator.toSlice();
string memory result = "";
var result_slice = result.toSlice();
result_slice = s_slice.split(seperator_slice);
return (result_slice.toString(), s_slice.toString());
}
```

it works perfectly fine, i checked it too.

if the input is "computer","p" to split string function, it returns "com" and "uter"

Here is the input i used for the `addentry` function - `"LC2","0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c","SP2","location:inside;reading:degree;protocol:http","scattr","ngac"` and tried to call the function from the same address in remix. the transaction was ssuccessful. Then I tried to look at the contents of the entry in struct array at position 0 and mapping key `"reading"` using the below function:

```
function getmappingentry(uint index, string s1) public returns (string, string)
{
    return (BCServiceList[index].cloudID, BCServiceList[index].serviceProducerMetadata[s1]);
}
```

The output is

```
{
    "0": "string: LC2",
    "1": "string: "
}
```

According to my understanding it should return

```
{
    "0": "string: LC2",
    "1": "string: degree"
}
```

Can someone help me understand what is missing here?

Thanks in advance!!!